# Java/Gradle: Copy folder from external .jar dependency to own build resource folder

Tags: css, gradle, javafx, fonts, materialfx

## Background

I have [MaterialFX](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX) as an external dependency for my JavaFx project. The project tries to recreate the demo shown in the MaterialFX project. My project uses Gradle (build script in Kotlin).

The demo uses custom fonts provided in its resource path in a `javaFxStylesheet.css` file to style e.g. the JavaFX Labels:

```css
/*javaFxStylesheet.css*/
@import '../fonts/Fonts.css';

.header {
    -fx-font-family: <fontname>`
}
```

where `Fonts.css` has multiple entries like

```css
/*Fonts.css*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa SemiBold';
    font-weight: 600px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('../fonts/Comfortaa/Comfortaa-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

## Problem

The MaterialFX dependency I pull into my project has the used fonts in a separate folder but how to I use them in my project. As is visible from the demo `Fonts.css` (which I would like to simply copy into my project), the paths to the fonts e.g. `url('../fonts/Comfortaa/Comfortaa-SemiBold.ttf')` are specified relative the resources path.

Now, if I want to use the same fonts in my project without changing all the paths, I guess I need to

1. Copy the `fonts`-Folder manually from the externally pulled materialfx.jar into my own project resources
2. Have Gradle automatically do this

So I imagine I need something like the following in my build.gradle:

```kotlin
copy from external library 'materialfx-11.13.9.jar' the folder 'io/github/palexdev/materialfx/font'
    into my own projects "src/main/resources"
```

Note - there seems to be a [smiliar issue](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-copy-a-folder-from-a-dependent-external-librarys-jar-into-the-gradle-projects-jar/35035/2) but I can't make it work as I have no clue if it even aims at the same thing I'm trying to acchieve.

Comment: Can't you just include the jar as a dependency and use the absolute path in your own project? I.e. `@import /io/github/palexdev/materialfx/css/Fonts.css;`?

Comment: I'm super new to java and javafx so maybe I don't get the structure but MaterialFX seems to be split into two sub-projects: the one I pull as the dependency from maven central (has no Fonts.css but folders with the fonts) and the demo project I don't pull (has the Font.css AND folders with the fonts). That leaves me with a dependency which has just the fonts. So I would need to reference the gradle dependency fonts folders in my Fonts.css AND change all the path references right?!

Comment: The demo isn't really part of the MaterialFX distribution, it is a separate standalone app [manually downloaded and installed from github](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/releases) rather than distributed through a build system like Maven.  The demo isn't built to be included in another application, it isn't a library.  All the demo source is available.  Perhaps, copy the source directories into your project and then make use of it that way, rather than having it in a separate jar, but that could be tricky as the demo is modular and has dependent 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Do you really want to recreate the entire MaterialsFX demo (if so, why?)  Or instead, are you just trying to use the same styling, widgets and fonts that it uses in the context of your own app UI, which has completely different functionality?